# Feeds import dynamic author change

Tags: feeds

I use Feeds so that logged users can upload data. I need to keep track of which user uploads what.

In Feeds importer 'Settings' you define the author, but in my case it should not be static but defined dynamically by the system.

How can I dynamically change that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure that users import content by creating a node. You can then map the author of that node to the author of the feed items that get created.

1. Make sure your importer is attached to a content type. Users can then import content by creating a node of that type. If you use the standalone import form, you cannot track which user uploaded what.
   [image: Attach importer to a content type]
2. Map "Feed node: User ID (parent:uid)" to "User ID (uid)". This will make sure that the author of all nodes that get created will be the same as the author that is set on the feed node.
   [image: Map "parent:uid" to "uid"]
   If you are using the CSV parser, manually enter `parent:uid` instead as source.
   [image: Map "parent:uid" to "uid" for CSV parser]

Comment: for CSV it did not work, I switched to this snippet:
     
       function mymodule_feeds_presave(FeedsSource $source, $entity, $item)
     {
       global $user;
       $entity->uid = $user->uid;
      }

Comment: That works as long as the content is imported using the UI only and periodic import is turned off. If content is imported via cron, then the current user is anonymous and the author of the imported content will be user 0.